# Python: Assign different values for the axis

Tags: scale, axis

I have a plot that is scaled from 1-30. I want to switch that to having 40 microns for every 1 increment. So a total from 1-1200, without changing the plot. Please help me modify the code. 
[Graph is shown in scale from 1-30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j2NG.png)

d_map = np.reshape(peaks1, (30,30)) #square 30x30, vary depends on the coding you run for your SERS

i_map = np.reshape(pos, (30,30))

print(len(peaks))

print(len(ind))

len(d_map)

figure(figsize=(10,10))

subplot(1,3,1)

imshow(d_map_1200,cmap='YlOrRd' )

colorbar()

Comment: `np` is not defined.

Comment: already defined it before, didn't include the beginning codes for nondisclosure reason. I just took out a part that I need help here. The defined part was

from matplotlib.pyplot import *

%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

from os import listdir

from os.path import isfile, join

import re